# Escaping closure cannot capture a mutating self(protocol/extension) parameter in swift5

Tags: swift5

I have tried to update this link [rotating UIView](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Rotatable) in swift 5.
But I have one issue in updating.

This is error line :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2)
        {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians)
        }
```

Comment: Please link the error here

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is because:

1. the protocol `Rotatable` can be implemented by value (`struct`) types; and
2. the function `mutating rotate(radians:, animated:)` implemented in the protocol extension contains an escaping closure which captures `self`.

Value types are *copied* (at least effectively) on assignment, so if a closure captures a *mutable* value type which *copy* is being mutated? Early Swift had a compromise semantics which did the expected thing most of the time, but produced confusing results at other times. Swift has since imposed greater restrictions to address this, the early Swift change proposal [*Limiting inout capture to @noescape contexts*](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0035-limit-inout-capture.md) explains the issues and was implemented in Swift 3.

The `Rotatable` protocol *can* be implemented by value types, but in the code you are converting it is only used for the *reference type* `UIView` and the code would have worked fine in Swift 2.

In current Swift one fix is to limit `Rotatable` to reference types:

```
protocol Rotatable : class { ... }
```

which also requires dropping all the uses of `mutable` – these are for value type compatibility. With those simple changes the code works.

*Note:* If the original author had implemented the protocol within the `UIView` extension (`extension UIView: Rotatable { func rotate(... }`), rather than in a seperate protocol extension (`extension Rotatable { ... }`) then the code would still have worked today without change.

If you wish to keep the protocol implementable by value types you can do so by moving the implementation into the `UIView` extension (you only have to move the single function `rotate(radians:, animated:)` if you wish as the remaining ones work for both value and reference types).

HTH